# GetPrivateProfileString without Trim?

Tags: c#, string, dllimport, ini

Being that this application has evolved over the years, there are still some INI files.  I have a class that reads entries using GetPrivateProfileString.

At the top of the class we see this:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
        string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal,
        int size, string filePath);
```

And it looks like there is a public method that looks something like this:

```
    public string IniReadValue(string Section, string Key)
    {
        // If string greater than 254 characters (255th spot is null-terminator),
        // string will be truncated.
        const int capacity = 255;
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(capacity);
        int i = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, "", temp,
                                        capacity, this.m_Path);
        return temp.ToString();
    }
```

I recently noticed that GetPrivateProfileString trims it's data.  Therefore, if my INI file has an entry like this:

SomeData=   Notice the three trailing spaces at front and back of this sentence.

It will retrieve it like (notice that it's trimmed to the left and right - ignore quotes):

"Notice the three trailing spaces at front and back of this sentence."

I don't want it to Trim.  Is that out of my control?  INI files aren't allowed to have spaces after the equal sign (e.g. SomeData=)?

Comment: you can always make your own parser

Comment: @Sam I am.  Yes, I agree.  I'm also curious about this particular function and why it has to trim the string.  Thank you for your input though, I've up-voted your comment.

Comment: Use double quotes in the ini file when you need leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: @Hans Passant, yeah, I thought of that.  But, the whole reason that I'm reading INI files is because of legacy code.  Therefore, in my new code I could introduce double-quotes, knowing that when I read it in later I can strip the quotes I added, but the legacy code would still read in the quotes.  WritePrivateProfileString doesn't trim spaces, why should GetPrivateProfileString?  It seems like it shouldn't manipulate data - it should just read it in as it's printed.  Thank you for your input though, I've up-voted your comment.

Comment: It's just the way the api works.  You can use an arbitrary number of spaces before and after the = character so trimming is inevitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, that is how the API works. If you can live with that, you can at least save some DllImport work by using for example this library/wrapper (includes source, just one file):

[IniReader](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/class.qpx?id=6)

Comment: I figured as much.  I was hoping that I overlooked some parameter that told it not to trim, or some newer function that didn't trim.  It doesn't make sense to me why it would Trim the string.  Why not return it to me un-changed and let me Trim if I desire?  Or if GetPrivateProfileString returns the string Trimmed, why doesn't WritePrivateProfileString write it Trimmed?  They go hand in hand, why not perform similarly?  In conclusion, I don't like it! :)  ... Anyhow, Thanks for your input, I'm going to give you the green check-mark.  Thanks again.

Comment: I did.  Thanks.  I wrote my own little parser (fairly simple) .. loop until I find my Section and if my Key is there, return the value (otherwise return a default value).

Answer (score 2):

You can use quotation marks to express your content, when read the content into a string,
you can easily to parse the content you want.
like this:
key = " content       "

and you can add some code in Function IniReadValue.

Or You can put/get the message use base64 string, like this:
some-key = your-content-in-base64-string
and many char issues would not be your problem.
But this way is not good for read.

Comment: Remember, I am using INI files because of legacy code.  Therefore, if I add quotes, the legacy code (without coding changes) will not know to parse the quotes.  I just ended up writing my own function: IniReadValueNoTrim.  Thanks for the input, I up-voted your answer for helping.  Thanks again.